# Memory issue even with the batch size 1 which training UNET

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am facing a weird issue while training my UNET like model. My system is GPU NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090, and I am using Keras version 2.6.0 .and tensorflow version 2.6.1. My training data contains nearly 1400 images of size 1024x1360 along with the masks. The training of this model is becoming extremely difficulty and I am facing weird following issues:

1. ResourceExhausted Error
2. Internal error: failed copying internal error.
3. When I reduce the training data to 15-20 images along with batch_size=1, it starts running but
   stops at a random epoch.

I can sense that the issue may be due to the huge training data but that's where the batch_size is useful. No sure what else I should try and fix the training. Please suggest.

Comment: What is the shape of your output tensor?

Comment: @Yaoshiang  its (None, 1024, 1360, 1)

Comment: What's your base model plugging into Unet and which Unet implementation are you using, qubvel?

Comment: I have resolved the issue using custom generator. Thanks @Yaoshiang